# How do I change this query to search for multiple values when 1 parameter is selected?

Tags: sql, oracle, birt

I have a report (BIRT) where the user selects a string value for one of the parameters. The value of that parameter is then used in one of the data set queries. What I want to accomplish is, when a particular value is selected, I need the report to also search for 1-3 other pre-defined values in the query. For example, if the user selects F-MAC, I want the data set to return all results where the category is F-MAC, as well as C-CDB, F-FMB, and M-MAC. If they select F-DAMAGE the data set should return all results where the category is F-DAMAGE as well as M-DAMAGE.

The parameter, Categories, is Static, with 4 values available.

Here is the query:

```
select
WO_WORKORDER,
WO_STATUS,
WO_DATE_COMPLETED,
PH_PHASE,
PH_STATUS,
WO_CATEGORY,
WO_CATEGORY_DESC,
WO_DEPT_DESC,
WO_DEPT_ID,
WO_FACILITY_DESC,
WO_BUILDING_DESC,
FTD_TRAN_TYPE,
FTD_AMOUNT,
FTD_TM_TYPE
from VW_WO_BILLING
where
WO_TYPE = 'F'
and WO_STATUS = 'CLOSED'
and PH_STATUS = 'CLOSED'
and FTD_TRAN_TYPE in ('CW','WX','TW','TP')
and WO_CATEGORY = ?
and
(wo_dept_id = ? or ? = 'ALL')
and TRUNC(WO_DATE_COMPLETED) >= ?
and TRUNC(WO_DATE_COMPLETED) <= ?
and FTD_AMOUNT <> 0
```

The ? for WO_CATEGORY is where the value selected in the parameter is passed into the query.

Answer (score 1):

I used this.queryText = this.queryText.replace with if/else statements in the beforeOpen script.

Answer (score 0):

You create another table for your combobox option

ComboBox `Table1`

```
Category_ID, Name
1,          F-MAC
2,          F-DAMAGE
```

Aditional Category  `Table2`

```
SubCategory_ID, Category_ID, Name
1               1             F-MAC
2               1             C-CDB
3               1             F-FMB
4               1             M-MAC
5               2             F-DAMAGE
6               2             M-DAMAGE
```

And update your query

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
   ON T1.Category_ID = T2.Category_ID   
INNER JOIN VW_WO_BILLING A
   ON T2.Name = A.WO_CATEGORY
WHERE
    Table1.Category_ID = ?
```

So if `CATEGORY_ID = 2` from combobox, then will match name `F-DAMAGE and M-DAMAGE` from the aditional table.